# "unicode argument without an encoding" when adding a byte to bytearray using extend

Tags: python, .net, arrays, ironpython, extend

I'm trying to build a bytearray out of a binary file as follows:

```
myArr = bytearray()
with open(r"C:\Users\User\MyFileName.bin", "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(1)
        while byte:
            myArr.extend(byte)
            byte = f.read(1)
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myScriptName.py", line 20, in testByteParsing
    myArr.extend(byte)
TypeError: unicode argument without an encoding
```

What is wrong in the above?

FWIW, I'm using IronPython

Comment: What is the full traceback for your exception? I cannot actually reproduce your error; I *can* spot a different one that may trigger the error elsewhere, or at the very least cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks. The traceback implies that the error occurs at `myArr.extend(byte)`

Comment: Can you *post* the traceback? The code posted in your answer certainly doesn't raise that exception.

Comment: Edited my question. Added the traceback and a note that I'm using IronPython.

Comment: Ah, that is an important distinction.

Comment: Sorry for not pointing it out in the first place.

Comment: are you quite sure about `byte != ""` ?

Comment: Try just to `encode` it to see what happens :P `myArr.extend(byte.encode())`

Comment: MartijnPieters and BurhanKhalid, I have edited the condition in the while loop.

Comment: @PauloBu, Thanks. I tried to, still the same.

Comment: @Subway I added `.net` tag to the question so maybe it can get more public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [IronPython's `bytearray` source code](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/1649294) I could see that `extend` method internally calls `GetBytes` method:

```
public void extend(object seq) {
    extend(GetBytes(seq));
}
```

and that actually, `GetBytes` method is hardwired to `except` when a `string` is given.

```
private static IList<byte>/*!*/ GetBytes(object/*!*/ value) {
    ListGenericWrapper<byte> genWrapper = value as ListGenericWrapper<byte>;
    if (genWrapper == null && value is IList<byte>) {
        return (IList<byte>)value;
    }

    if (value is string || value is Extensible<string>) {
        throw PythonOps.TypeError("unicode argument without an encoding");
    }

    List<byte> ret = new List<byte>();
    IEnumerator ie = PythonOps.GetEnumerator(value);

    while (ie.MoveNext()) {
        ret.Add(GetByte(ie.Current));
    }
    return ret;
    }
```

So I would recommend to convert the byte read from the file to an integer value within 0-255 with the [`ord()`](http://ironpython-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/library/functions.html#ord) function and then use append to insert it in the `bytearray`.

Your code can remain like this:

```
myArr = bytearray()
with open(r"C:\Users\User\MyFileName.bin", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte:
        myArr.append(ord(byte))
        byte = f.read(1)
```

That's somehow ugly, I think they implemented this this way in compliance with some .NET library's restraints.

Perhaps someone more familiarized with IronPython can provide a more elegant solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. Using the posted code I'm getting: `myArr.extend(ord(byte)) TypeError: int is not iterable`

Comment: @Subway take a look, it is not `extend`, it is `append`.

Comment: It's a side-effect of IronPython's weird string encoding - `str` maps to `System.String`, which is Unicode, unlike CPython 2. bytearray.extend should probably handle this case to stay compatible, but it may introduce other oddities. IronPython 3 will be consistent with Python 3 and make all of this (hopefully) go away.

Comment: @JeffHardy At first I was looking for an optional parameter to provide an encoding. Actually `bytearray('hello','utf8')` for example, works. I was looking a way to set an encoding for `extend` but I didn't find it. Thanks for the explanation!